# Does rsync link to exact files or just files with the same name?

Tags: macos, terminal, backup, rsync, apfs

I wrote a little rsync backup script for my recently replaced computer (internal HD to external HD).

When I got the new computer, I copied the files over (old internal HD to new internal HD). Same file structure, filenames, etc.

I'm wondering whether I can just run the backup script on the new computer which is now hooked up to the old external HD.

The potential problem I foresee revolves around whether rsync links to exact files or just filenames.

I remember reading something about filesystems have specific identifiers (a serial number or something) "under the hood" for each file and changing the name does not change that number.

So, if rsync links to that number instead of just a filename in a particular position in the directory structure, it might make a total mess of the external HD by recopying everything in duplicate or some other strange outcome.

It's just that rsync works using hard/soft links, and I'm not enough of an expert on that to know the specifics or their implications...

Any help appreciated!

MacOS Ventura 13.4.1, APFS (filesystem)

Comment: I'm pretty sure it just uses file paths/names. keep in mind it supports basically any filesystem type the hosts do, and can even deal with network virtual filesystems like SMB and NFS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### tl;dr

There is nothing to worry about. Make your script use [`rsync --dry-run --verbose …`](https://download.samba.org/pub/rsync/rsync.1#opt--dry-run) and see for yourself. If it looks sane, keep using the original script (without `--dry-run`).

---

#### Inode numbers

> I remember reading something about filesystems have specific identifiers (a serial number or something) "under the hood" for each file and changing the name does not change that number.

[Inode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inode) numbers. Native filesystems in Unix/Linux commonly use the concept (and macOS is Unix). Filesystems that don't internally use inodes appear as if they used them, so they can be handled in a similar way. So yes, files do have serial numbers, `ls -i` prints them.

> So, if rsync links to that number instead of just a filename…

**`rsync` does not base on inode numbers, it uses [pathnames](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_271)** (and pathnames consist of [filenames](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_170)). Inode numbers are not designed to mean anything outside their filesystem. And I don't mean a filesystem type; I mean they are internal to their particular instance of a filesystem, not connected to inode numbers in another filesystem (even of the same type).

You are right that if `rsync` tried to base on inode numbers, it could wreak havoc. It does not do this. AFAIK [there is no standard interface to access files by inode numbers](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/92816/108618). And you (or `rsync`) cannot request a certain number while creating a new file. For filesystems that don't use inodes and only appear as if they used them, inode numbers may be generated on the fly and in many (all?) cases there is no guarantee the exact same numbers are associated with exact same files after you unmount and mount such filesystem again.

All this means that programs should not care about inode numbers, unless they are supposed to deal with guts of a filesystem itself. Inode numbers are internal to the filesystem. Programs like `cp` or `rsync` should work on a different level of abstraction and they do. The different level of abstraction is the directory tree with pathnames.

One scenario where inode numbers "leak out" and are (safely) used by such programs is when a program wants to spot hardlinks. Hardlinked files are two or more pathnames leading to a single file (inode number). Programs can compare inode numbers and thus tell which pathnames lead to the same file. Hardlinks work only within a single filesystem; files that happen to have identical inode numbers but exist in different filesystems are not related, programs take that into account.

E.g. in `rsync` you can use the `--hard-links`/`-H` option:

> This tells `rsync` to look for hard-linked files in the source and link together the corresponding files on the destination. Without this option, hard-linked files in the source are treated as though they were separate files.
>
> […]
>
> Note that rsync can only detect hard links between files that are inside the transfer set. […]

<sup>([source: `man 1 rsync`](https://download.samba.org/pub/rsync/rsync.1#opt--hard-links))</sup>

`rsync -H` tries to spot hardlinks in the source and create hardlinks on the destination. But even then inode numbers on the destination will have nothing to do with inode numbers in the source. When `rsync -H` notices some pathnames in the source lead to the same inode number within the same filesystem then it will try to make the corresponding pathnames on the destination to lead to *some* single inode number; in other words it will try to make hardlinked files. What exactly the number will be is outside of the scope (and abilities) of `rsync`. The tool does not need to care about the number, as even the interface to create hardlinks (`link(2)`) uses pathnames, not inode numbers.

---

#### Can I just run the backup script?

> I copied the files over (old internal HD to new internal HD). Same file structure, filenames, etc. I'm wondering whether I can just run the backup script on the new computer which is now hooked up to the old external HD.

**You can.** The inode numbers in the new source may be (and most likely are) totally different than the inode numbers in the old source, but this does not matter at all. Identical directory structure of the source is enough.

Remember there is [`--dry-run`/`-n`](https://download.samba.org/pub/rsync/rsync.1#opt--dry-run). **To be on the safe side**, create a copy of your script and make it use `rsync --dry-run --verbose …` or so; run it and analyze the output. Problems you will encounter (if any) will have nothing to do with inode numbers though.

Comment: Wow.  This is an amazing answer.  Not only did you provide a solid answer, you also gave interesting background information and a very helpful suggestion.  You are officially the best answerer in the history of the internet!   ;)